# Is there a concise notation for a solution of one substance in another?

Tags: solutions, notation

I'm aware of phase notation of $\ce{(aq)}$ for aqueous solutions. Is there something similar for solutions of chemical X dissolved in chemical Y?

Comment: Welcome to Chem.SE! I edited your post a bit for clarity -- if you don't like my changes, please feel free to roll them back (click either "edit", or the "edited [time]" above my name).  I feel like I've come across something like this at some point, but I don't remember anything specific. Hopefully someone'll know.  Please take a look at the [tour] and the [help] for more info about the site -- enjoy!

Comment: X / Y will do$\!$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Phase abbreviations for non-aqueous solutions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/108173/phase-abbreviations-for-non-aqueous-solutions)